# API is accepting requests from other OAuth domains

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, oauth2

I've set an OAuth domain for an application (the `client_id` is 24) and the following link authorizes the application:

> https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=24&scope=no_expiry,read_inbox&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success

I can assure you that the `redirect_uri` is **not** within the registered domain for my application.

Why is this not producing an error?

Comment: I think the only URL outside the registered domain that is accepted is `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`, because it's on StackExchange it's trusted already.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yeah, but that isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You'll note on the authentication documentation:

> Desktop applications cannot participate directly in OAuth 2.0 flows,
>   however the embeddable browser controls available in most frameworks
>   make it possible to work around this limitation.
>
> Desktop applications should use the implicit client-side flow, hosting
>   the process within a browser control. For redirect_uri, a value of
>   https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success should be used. Upon a
>   successful authentication, access_token will be placed in the url hash
>   as with a standard implicit authentication.

However, I can see that some developers may want the peace of mind that comes from this not being available.

You can now disable this behavior on your application's edit page.

[image]